# SharePoint Survey - How to save one survey as a template

Tags: sharepoint-online, survey, rating

Scenario:
I have a list of 50+ vendors.
I have 4 departments (likely only 1 user per dept will be filling out the survey)
I have created a survey for the first one one the list.
I am now tasked with duplicating this survey for each of the remaining vendors. (kill me now)
It appears that regular old lists and libraries can be saved as templates, but I am not seeing this option for this survey.  I even went into SP Designer (my bff) and clicked "save as template" ... only to be told that I did not have access (I own the dang site), so for kicks, I requested access and granted myself full access ... but it just kept happening over again.
So I'm wondering if this is even possible.
(Did I mention that I'm using SP ONLINE?)
OR ...
I originally thought that maybe I could simply implement the star rating to the original list of vendors ... the stars are very cool as well .. and more straightforward .. but of course the SP gods decided to not allow the same person to rate the same vendor more than once.  Dang it!!!
The same 4 people will be rating the same list of vendors after each interaction (for response time, accuracy, punctuality, etc) so I really need the ability to rate them multiple times, therefore affecting the overall rating over time.  I hope this makes sense.
It's funny because there's actually a setting to allow this in the survey app under survey settings:list name description and navigation: allow multiple responses!
Based on the information I have provided (or over-provided .. sorry), can someone please advise whether I can:
1.  Duplicate a vendor survey by making the original a template ... or some other magical way.
2.  Tweak the system somehow to allow users to rate something multiple times.
3.  Or maybe you'd do it an entirely different way?  I'm humbly open to suggestions!
Thanks very much for your patience!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are suing Survey App, you can choose to select Survey Settings > Save survey as template to proceed:

[image]

If the option is simply missing, try to [enable custom script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script) . As go through UI will take about 24 hours, it will be better to use powershell.

```
$adminUPN="UPN"
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Type the password."
Connect-SPOService -Url https://domian name-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $userCredential
Set-SPOsite <site URL> -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

And you can also have a try with [Microsoft Forms](https://forms.office.com/) You can easily copy and paste it. If you are going to deploy it for each vendor (I assume they all have separate sites). Simply use [SharePoint Forms web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-microsoft-forms-web-part-d4b4d3ce-7860-41e4-8a98-76380efe7256) to refer to the form in different sites.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a provisioning template based on that list as well by using  [PnP Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps).

To create a template, use [Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpprovisioningtemplate)

By using a combination of the `Handlers` and `ListsToExtract` flag you can narrow it down to your survey list.

You can then create a script to provision this to all your sites and enjoy a coffee or two while it does the job for you! The relevant command to apply it back to a site is [Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/apply-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps)

Edit: I think maybe you want all of these on one site? In that case you would need to modify the script to generate a new list name for each vendor by editing the xml file for each `Apply`